Curly bracket on the side of a proof tree (ebproof package)
I have the following code that produces a proof tree and I need to denote a part of the proof by $\pi'$ and use a curly bracket on the right (or left) side (see picture. I don't need the red dots)
.
I found this post and this post, which are for equations and tikz trees respectively.
I tried the first one but I don't know how to "select" only a part of the proof. When trying  I broke the proof in two trees, but I destroyed the automatic alignment which is better to be kept since I will be adding soon extra inference below the existent tree.
I also tried the solution using tikz, but I failed with the relative coordinations and the bracket was wrongly positioned. Plus I don't know how to use tikz.
%Typeset using XeLaTeX

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathabx,bm, mathdots}

\usepackage{ebproof}%proof trees

\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{bboldx}%for ordinal notations, LuaTeX, XeTeX

\usepackage{ucharclasses}%automated hyphenation, XeTeX


\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
%languages
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek}


\usepackage{color}
%COMMANDS

\newcommand{\succes}[1]{{s}^{#1}(0)}
\newcommand{\bbzero}{\mathbb{0}}
\newcommand{\bbone}{\mathbb{1}}


\newcommand{\bbomega}{\text{\textbb{\char 127}}}
\newcommand{\bbplus}{\text{\textbb{\char 43}}}


\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}

\newcommand{\bluelabel}[1]{{\color{ao}#1}}
\newcommand{\pinklabel}[1]{{\color{amaranth}#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    %The code with curly bracket selecting the whole proof (incorrect)
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        &\begin{rcases}\begin{prooftree}
                \hypo{}
                \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}(a)$}{}
                \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}}\quad \Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\phi[a]} 
                \infer[dashed]1[R$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}\bbplus \bbone}\quad\Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\forall x \phi[x]}
                \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}'$}{}
                \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\alpha_{1},r} \quad\Gamma,\Gamma \vdash \Theta, \forall x \phi[x] }
                \hypo{}
                \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{2}$}{}
                \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}}\quad \phi[\succes{n}],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}} 
                \infer[dashed]1[L$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}\bbplus \bbone}\quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}}
                \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{2}'$}{}
                \infer[no rule]1[]{\bluelabel{\alpha_{2},r} \quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta \vdash \Lambda  }
                \infer[left label={\footnotesize CUT I}]2{}
        \end{prooftree}\end{rcases}&\pi'\\ 
        &\begin{prooftree}
            \hypo{\bluelabel{\bbomega_{r-s}(a_{1}\sharp a_{2}),s}\quad \Gamma,\Delta\vdash \Theta,\Lambda}
            \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{4}$}{}
            \infer[no rule]1[]{ \Pi \vdash \Xi  }
        \end{prooftree}
    \end{alignat*}
    
    %The code without curly bracket.
    \[\begin{prooftree}
        \hypo{}
        \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}(a)$}{}
        \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}}\quad \Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\phi[a]} 
        \infer[dashed]1[R$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}\bbplus \bbone}\quad\Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\forall x \phi[x]}
        \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}'$}{}
        \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\alpha_{1},r} \quad\Gamma,\Gamma \vdash \Theta, \forall x \phi[x] }
        \hypo{}
        \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{2}$}{}
        \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}}\quad \phi[\succes{n}],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}} 
        \infer[dashed]1[L$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}\bbplus \bbone}\quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}}
        \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{2}'$}{}
        \infer[no rule]1[]{\bluelabel{\alpha_{2},r} \quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta \vdash \Lambda  }
        \infer[left label={\footnotesize CUT I}]2{\bluelabel{\bbomega_{r-s}(a_{1}\sharp a_{2}),s}\quad \Gamma,\Delta\vdash \Theta,\Lambda}
        \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{4}$}{}
        \infer[no rule]1[]{ \Pi \vdash \Xi  }
    \end{prooftree}\]
    
    %   %The code using tikz for curly bracket
    %   
    %   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 2cm,minimum height=1cm]
        %       
        %       \node (A){$\begin{prooftree}
                %               \hypo{}
                %               \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}(a)$}{}
                %               \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}}\quad \Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\phi[a]} 
                %               \infer[dashed]1[R$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}\bbplus \bbone}\quad\Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\forall x \phi[x]}
                %               \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}'$}{}
                %               \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\alpha_{1},r} \quad\Gamma,\Gamma \vdash \Theta, \forall x \phi[x] }
                %               \hypo{}
                %               \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{2}$}{}
                %               \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}}\quad \phi[\succes{n}],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}} 
                %               \infer[dashed]1[L$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}\bbplus \bbone}\quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}}
                %               \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{2}'$}{}
                %               \infer[no rule]1[]{\bluelabel{\alpha_{2},r} \quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta \vdash \Lambda  }
                %               \infer[left label={\footnotesize CUT I}]2{\bluelabel{\bbomega_{r-s}(a_{1}\sharp a_{2}),s}\quad \Gamma,\Delta\vdash \Theta,\Lambda}
                %               \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{4}$}{}
                %               \infer[no rule]1[]{ \Pi \vdash \Xi  }
                %           \end{prooftree}$};
        %       \node[below=of A] (B){\phantom{}};
        %       \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm},black](A)--node {$\pi'$}(B);
        %   \end{tikzpicture}
    %   
    %       
\end{document}


We can make the ebproof to look shorter by embedding it in a tabular where a negative spacing is added. A compensating vertical space ia added later.
I made some changes to the code: \textcolor{<color>}{<text>} is better than {\color{<color>}<text>}.
Loading packages in the middle of code can be confusing, so I moved all of them at the beginning. In particular, since tikz already loads xcolor you can avoid messages about bad color definitions.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathabx,bm, mathdots}
\usepackage{bboldx}%for ordinal notations, LuaTeX, XeTeX

\usepackage{ebproof}%proof trees
%\usepackage{ucharclasses}%automated hyphenation, XeTeX

% font
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
%languages
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek}

%COMMANDS
\newcommand{\succes}[1]{{s}^{#1}(0)}
\newcommand{\bbzero}{\mathbb{0}}
\newcommand{\bbone}{\mathbb{1}}
\newcommand{\bbomega}{\text{\textbb{\char 127}}}
\newcommand{\bbplus}{\text{\textbb{\char 43}}}

\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}

\newcommand{\bluelabel}[1]{\textcolor{ao}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pinklabel}[1]{\textcolor{amaranth}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here's the proof with the brace only covering the part we want
\[
\begin{gathered}
\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{}
  \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}(a)$}{}
  \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}}\quad \Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\phi[a]} 
  \infer[dashed]1[R$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{1}\bbplus \bbone}
    \quad\Gamma_{1} \vdash \Theta_{1},\forall x \phi[x]}
  \ellipsis{\color{amaranth}$\pi_{1}'$}{}
  \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\alpha_{1},r} \quad\Gamma,\Gamma \vdash \Theta, \forall x \phi[x] }
  \hypo{}
  \ellipsis{\pinklabel{$\pi_{2}\mathstrut$}}{}
  \infer[no rule]1{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}}\quad \phi[\succes{n}],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}} 
  \infer[dashed]1[L$\forall$]{\bluelabel{\beta_{2}\bbplus \bbone}
    \quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta_{1} \vdash \Lambda_{1}}
  \ellipsis{\pinklabel{$\pi_{2}'$}}{}
  \infer[no rule]1[]{\bluelabel{\alpha_{2},r} \quad \forall x \phi[x],\Delta \vdash \Lambda  }
  \infer[left label={\footnotesize CUT I}]2{\bluelabel{\bbomega_{r-s}(a_{1}\sharp a_{2}),s}
    \quad \Gamma,\Delta\vdash \Theta,\Lambda}
  \ellipsis{\pinklabel{$\pi_{4}$}}{}
  \infer[no rule]1[]{ \Pi \vdash \Xi  }
  \end{prooftree}
\\[-7ex]
\end{tabular}
\right\}\pi'
\\
\vspace*{5ex}
\end{gathered}
\]
Here's text below the display to show that there's no overlap.

\end{document}


The \mathstrut trick adds an invisible character as high as (, so the ellipses on the top right are as high as those at top left.

I would have never noticed that the ellipses on the top right weren't as high as those at top left. Thank you!
I don't understand some things. Could you please explain? Why should I make the proof tree look shorter? How does the curly bracket "know" the height needed so that it doesn't cover the last ellipses? How does \mathstrut work? I can only see that you have added mathstrut in \ellipsis{\pinklabel{$\pi_{2}\mathstrut$}}{}. Does it "think" that there is an extra higher character inside \pinklabel?

I think I understand. I tried making the next proof tree and by changing [-7ex] to [..-x...ex] I could regulate the  height of the bottom half of the curly bracket. I then changed \vspace*{5ex} to \vspace*{...x...ex}.
And the problem with the top right and top left ellipses was (as I understand it) that the left had parentheses, while the right one didn't. Would it be the same to add \vphantom{(}? I saw this post.
Thanks for the corrections too!

@ΝικολέταΣεβαστού \mathstrut is exactly the same as \vphantom{(}. If we make the object to look shorter, then TeX will apply \right\} to the perceived size. Of course we need to compensate for the “missed part” later. Why -7ex? By experimenting. Why 5ex to compensate? Because gathered adds some vertical space between rows.
